# Citing the source of an equation?

Tags: equations, citing

I cant find a good way of adding a `\cite` to an equation. I'd like to give a reference to the equation's source, but I can't figure out how to typeset it nicely. If I include it in with the equation itself, it pushes the alignment leftwards and feel too much like it's invading the equation's space. I've tried putting an `\hfill\cite{example}` on the line after the equation, but there's too much vertical space between the equation and the reference.

I'd love to know if there's a commonly accepted way of doing this that I haven't managed to find. Failing that, if anyone has any not-too-inelegant compromises, that'd be great too.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It would be also great if you canadd a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: What would be wrong with something like `\begin{equation}\label{1}...\end{equation}`, and then `Equation~\ref{1} can be found in \cite{}` (or before the equation, maybe)?

Comment: @Tbbe: you can always use the [_marginnote_](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) package. Compare [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97237/marginpar-and-beginalign).

Comment: Thank you @ canaaerus it could be a solution! I'll dig deeper into marginnote and see what it can.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You shouldn't add the references inside the equation IMO, but outside as in this code:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
From the famous inequality math relation~\cite{companion}
\begin{equation}
  y \neq x
\end{equation}
%
Or you can also say:
\begin{equation}
  y \neq x
\end{equation}
as proved by~\cite{companion} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thus leaving equations to themselves. This reduces the confusion between the parameters and the citation number. (Equations are equations - Don't put something else inside `:-)`)

Comment: Fair enough - I wasn't sure if there was a commonly-accepted way to incorporate the reference into the equation line, but if not, then that'll have to do. Thanks very much!

Comment: _Equations are equations - Don't put something else inside :-)_: except punctuation marks maybe. Touchy topic :D

Comment: I would write the second reference as `as proved in Ref.~\cite{companion}.` or `as proved by~\citeauthor{companion}.`. Oh, and add punctuation to the equations.

Answer (score 9):

The following solution only works for the standard environment `equation` *without* package `amsmath`. It stores the cite command in macro `\@eqcite`, which is then set left to the equation number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\eqcite}[1]{%
  \def\@eqcite{\org@cite{#1}}%
}
\let\@eqcite\@empty
\def\@eqnnum{%
  {%
    \normalfont
    \normalcolor
    \ifx\@eqcite\@empty
    \else
      \@eqcite\space
    \fi
    (\theequation)%
  }%
}
\g@addto@macro\equation{%
  \let\org@cite\cite
  \let\cite\eqcite
}
\let\org@cite\cite
\makeatother

\begin{document}
The famous inequality math relation:
\begin{equation}
  y \neq x \cite{companion}
\end{equation}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The MWE is based on Harish Kumar's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82779/16967).

## Different lines

As requested in the comment, a version with the equation number and citation on different lines. IMHO, also this does not look better. The implementation can be done via a `tabular`. The optional argument controls the vertical alignment of the two lines with respect to the base line of the equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\eqcite}[1]{%
  \def\@eqcite{\org@cite{#1}}%
}
\let\@eqcite\@empty
\def\@eqnnum{%
  {%
    \normalfont
    \normalcolor
    \ifx\@eqcite\@empty
      (\theequation)%
    \else
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{}}(\theequation)\\\@eqcite\end{tabular}%
    \fi
  }%
}
\g@addto@macro\equation{%
  \let\org@cite\cite
  \let\cite\eqcite
}
\let\org@cite\cite
\makeatother

\begin{document}
The famous inequality math relation:
\begin{equation}
  y \neq x \cite{companion}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result different lines]

## Citation in line below with `\vadjust`

In the previous example, the equation moves to the left, because the available space is reduced by the longer citation in the author/year style.

`\llap` could be used for the citation, but the risk for overprinting the equation is much too large. The following example puts the citation below the equation via `\vadjust`. Again it only works for LaTeX without package `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*{\eqcite}[1]{%
  \vadjust{%
    \smallskip
    \hbox to \linewidth{\hfill\cite{#1}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
The famous inequality math relation:
\begin{equation}
  y \neq x
  \eqcite{companion}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with citation below equation using \vadjust]

Comment: Yes, that is very neat and use of LaTeX script at a level I'd never find out myself!

Comment: Sorry to ask for more, but is there an easy way to update the macro and place equation number and citation on different lines?

Comment: @Tbbe See updated answer.

Comment: It's just perfect! It also inspires me to learn more.

Comment: Hello, I found there is a problem when a page break was located between the equation and the `\eqcite`. These two (`\eqcite` and the equation) should not be separated into two pages. Is there a way to resolve it?

Comment: @Y.zeng Try adding `\nobreak` right before `\smallskip` in the example with `\vadjust`.

Answer (score 4):

A Johnny-come-lately solution, using `stackengine`.  This first approach only works in the standard `equation` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@ARTICLE{myref,
  AUTHOR = "last, first",
  TITLE = "This is the title",
  JOURNAL = "The Lancet",
  YEAR = "2014"
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\newcommand\citeequation[2]{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{$\displaystyle#1$}{\makebox[\linewidth]{\hfill \cite{#2}\kern20pt}}
    {O}{c}{F}{T}{L}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\citeequation{E=mc^2}{myref}
\end{equation}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's an alternate approach that works with `align` and `aligned`, where `\aligncite` must be called immediately after the alignment point, but requires, for the first in the set of `aligncite` calls, to have the optional argument tuned to the particular equation.  When no optional argument is used, it uses the previous setting.

`\alkerndefault` is the default offset of the cite from the margin, for the case of a perfectly centered (baseline) alignment point (set to 20pt here).  `alkernbias` is the bias to be applied for any given `align` set of equations.  While set here to 0pt, it is globally redefined whenever the optional argument to `\aligncite` is employed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,filecontents,amsmath}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@ARTICLE{myref,
  AUTHOR = "last, first",
  TITLE = "This is the title",
  JOURNAL = "The Lancet",
  YEAR = "2014"
}
@ARTICLE{myref2,
  AUTHOR = "last, first",
  TITLE = "Next title",
  JOURNAL = "JAP",
  YEAR = "2015"
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\newcommand\alkerndefault{20pt}% DETERMINES OFFSET OF BASELINE (CENTERED) CASE
\newcommand\alkernbias{0pt}% BIAS TO SHIFT WHEN ALIGNMENT POINT IS NOT CENTERED
\newcommand\aligncite[2][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\else\gdef\alkernbias{#1}\fi\def\alkern{\alkernbias}%
  \stackengine{0pt}{}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\dimexpr\alkerndefault]{%
    \hfill \protect\cite{#2}\kern-\dimexpr\alkern}}
    {O}{c}{F}{T}{L}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  Baseline/&\aligncite{myref}/Baseline
\end{align}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 E &\aligncite[33.5pt]{myref}= mc^2\\
 y &\aligncite{myref2}= Ax^2 + Bx + C
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
 y &\aligncite{myref2}= mx + b\\
 E &\aligncite[18pt]{myref}= mc^2
\end{align}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

[image]