# \marginpar and \begin{align}

Tags: align, marginpar

I want to use `\marginpar` directly beside a formula within a `\begin{align}` statement. I tried:

```
\begin{align}
E^2
\end{align}
\marginpar{Not correct}
```

but the 'Not correct' statement is written besides the next line. How can I achieve that is is written besides E^2 (means on the same height)?

And what if I have more than one formula, how to achieve to write it besides the very last of the align-environment?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use the [`marginnote`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) package and use its `\marginnote` command. `\marginnote` is a non-floating version of `\marginpar` and can also be used *inside* the `align` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 E^2 \marginnote{Not correct}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]