# Will todonotes work inside an align environment?

Tags: align, incompatibility, todonotes

Is it possible to use todonotes inside an align environment, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a^2&=b^2+c^2 \todo{check this calculation}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

gives me the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.8 \end{align}

? X
No pages of output.
Transcript written on foo.log.
```

What are some alternatives? I have tried the marginnote package, but it doesn't have the `inline` feature.

Comment: AFAIK, a todonote is essentially a `\marginpar` so no, I don't think it is possible to do that. Can't tell you the exact reason though. But on page 14 in the manual (if on Windows 7, Ubuntu and maybe OS X: search for todonotes.pdf) is some alternative: wrap it around the `align` environment.

Comment: @henry I did search the documentation for "align", and saw the alternative you describe, but (if I understand correctly) that is related to aligning an equation within a todo note, rather than vice-versa.

Comment: It’s not pretty and it may not be the best solution (I don’t know a lot about math mode since I don’t usually typeset math), but it works: `\text{\todo[inline]{check this calculation}}`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## `todonotes`

As mentioned in [\marginpar and \begin{align}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97237/marginpar-and-beginalign) `\marginpar` that is used by `todonotes` doesn't work inside `align`, but `\marginnote` from the `marginnote` package does. Hence, you could redefine a command from `todonotes` to use `marginnote`, and it works. Three compilation passes is needed.

[image: code output]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@todonotes@drawMarginNoteWithLine}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, baseline=-0.75ex]%
    \node [coordinate] (inText) {};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\marginnote[{% Draw note in left margin
    \@todonotes@drawMarginNote%
    \@todonotes@drawLineToLeftMargin%
}]{% Draw note in right margin
    \@todonotes@drawMarginNote%
    \@todonotes@drawLineToRightMargin%
}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a^2&=b^2+c^2 \todo{check this calculation}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

## `luatodonotes`

If you're using `lualatex` to compile your documents, then replacing `todonotes` with `luatodonotes` is another option.

(Note (for TeX Live 2015 users at least):  at the moment there is a problem with `luatex.sty`, which is loaded by `luatodonotes`, so [a small patch suggested by David Carlisle in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25298384#25298384) is 
required.)

[image]

```
% ---------
% temporarily required
\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@luatex.sty}{}
\makeatother
% ----------
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{luatodonotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a^2&=b^2+c^2 \todo{check this calculation}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: \@todonotes@drawMarginNoteWithLine undefined.`?

Comment: @David are you using an older version of `todonotes` perhaps, I copied the definition directly from `todonotes.sty`. Add `\listfiles` to your preamble to get a list of packages and versions printed at the end of the log file. My log file says `todonotes.sty    2012/07/25`.

Comment: that answer worked nicely at least in texlive 2015, however after an upgrade to texlive 2019, I obtain the following error:
./todo-equation.tex:21: Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> $
l.21 a^2=b^2+c^2 \todo{Test} ./todo-equation.tex:21: Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again> \par l.21 a^2=b^2+c^2 \todo{Test} ./todo-equation.tex:22: You can't use `\eqno' in vertical mode.
\endequation ->\eqno \hbox {\@eqnnum }$$\@ignoretrue l.22 \end{equation} ./todo-equation.tex:22: Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> any idea what to do? thanks Uwe Brauer

Comment: Using \text{\todo{check this calculation}} seems to solve. I got the same error without texting it.