# Is it possible for todonote to work inside a math environment?

Tags: todonotes

I am trying to get `\todo` command to work inside math. A solution is proposed in [Will todonotes work inside an align environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132449/will-todonotes-work-inside-an-align-environment), but the thread is outdated. Is it possible to redefine the current `\todo` command and get it to work inside math environments?

The solution proposed by [user23623](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/299596/user23623) works when renewing the command `\todo` as mentioned by [Fix todo in math mode.](https://github.com/henrikmidtiby/todonotes/pull/41), but the notes overlap when they are large

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@todonotes@drawMarginNoteWithLine}{\marginpar}{\marginnote}{}{}
\renewcommand{\todo}[2][]%
{%
    % Needed to output any dangling \item of a noskip section (see #36):
    \if@inlabel \leavevmode \fi
    \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
    \if@todonotes@inlinepar
    \ifvmode
    \@savsf\@m
    \@savsk\z@
    \@todonotes@vmodetrue
    \else
    \@bsphack
    \@todonotes@vmodefalse
    \fi
    {\@todo[#1]{#2}}%
    \@esphack%
    \if@todonotes@vmode \par \fi
    \else%
    \@todo[#1]{#2}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother
\NewDocumentCommand{\todosample}{}{This text is intended as a sample for todo tests}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{align}
        a^2&=b^2+c^2
        \todo{check this calculation}
    \end{align}
    
    Text%
    \todo{\todosample}
    
    Text%
    \todo{\todosample}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is almost literally a copy of [the answer you link to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132451/299596) except that this implementation uses `xpatch` to replace `\marginpar` by `\marginnote` in `\@todonotes@drawMarginNoteWithLine`, which gets called by `\todo`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@todonotes@drawMarginNoteWithLine}{\marginpar}{\marginnote}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    a^2&=b^2+c^2
    \text{\todo{check this calculation}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The advantage of using `xpatch` is that this continues to work when the package gets updated as long as the heart of the problem remains the same. In the case at hand, this seems to fix the issue. Notice, though, that I also wrapped `\todo{check this calculation}` into `\text{...}`. This can be automatized (or patched) as well, but the cleaner way to go will be to contact the package authors and ask for an upgrade.

Comment: This causes notes to overlap when their contents is large