# Aligning citation and number of an equation

Tags: equations, citing

I have an equation that is taken from a book, so naturally I have to cite it. 
How I would like to do it:

> ```
>               x+y=z (in the middle)          [4](1.1) (on the right)
> ```

In which [4] would link to the corresponding citation (I do that using \citep{...}) and (1.1) would be the first equation in section 1 - both of that work on their own.

For the equations in general I go for

```
\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}
```

using the

```
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
```

for the number

I tried adding the citation on the right side with \tag*{...} but this makes the number of the equation disappear.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet  compilable!

Comment: Unusual demand ... people usually in similar circumstances write something like this: `... considering \citep{...}: \begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`. This is more clear and easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is answered in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251979

Please check the link it has a solution for referenced equation and I think this is your aim.