# How to write at the page margin inside a centered equation?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I want to make a citation inside a centered equation, and want the citation indicator ("[1]") to be at the right side of the equation, where the equation number would normally go. In general, is there a way to write things on the margin of the page, inside a centered equation?

-

## MWE

Right now I have:

```
\begin{document}
    
\[(10^{11} +1)=11^2\cdot23\cdot4093\cdot8779 \,. \raggedleft\cite{prime page}\]


\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    
    \bibitem{prime page}
    Makoto Kamada,
    \textit{Factorization of 100...001},
    \url{http://stdkmd.com/nrr/repunit/10001.htm} (Accessed: 30/03/2018)
    
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Which outputs:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can adjust this answer to your needs: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251979/134144

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bernard's answer is good, but `amsmath` provides `\tag*` that allows a citation
like this to be entered directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\[ (10^{11} +1)=11^2\cdot23\cdot4093\cdot8779 \,.
\tag*{\cite{prime page}} \]
\begin{equation}\label{test}
    a = b
\end{equation}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{prime page}
Makoto Kamada,
\textit{Factorization of 100...001},
\url{http://stdkmd.com/nrr/repunit/10001.htm} (Accessed: 30/03/2018)

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: The question is (not to you, of course): how will the reader understand this is a citation callout?

Comment: @egreg: *If* the paper is being read on-screen, rather than on paper, maybe the greenish look of the number will make the reader try cliking on it… ;-)

Comment: @GuM My preferred PDF reader doesn't pollute the screen with thin colored rectangles.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the `\newtagform` command from `mathtools` (needless to load `amsmath` in this case):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{simple}{}{}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\tagcite}[1]{\usetagform{simple}\tag{\cite{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\[ (10^{11} +1)=11^2\cdot23\cdot4093\cdot8779 \,.
\tagcite{prime page} \]
\begin{equation}\label{test}
    a = b
\end{equation}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{prime page}
Makoto Kamada,
\textit{Factorization of 100...001},
\url{http://stdkmd.com/nrr/repunit/10001.htm} (Accessed: 30/03/2018)

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]